# How to change the sign to a decimal number in C#

Tags: c#, console, numbers, decimal, sign

I need a console app that changes the sign to a certain typed number. You type 10, it gives you -10. And so on. I've managed to do that, but I can't do it if I type 1.5 for example. Or any decimal number.
I get "Input string was not in a correct format".
this is what I did.

```
string inputData = Console.ReadLine();
int a = Convert.ToInt32 (inputData);
int b = a * (-1);
Console.WriteLine(b);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You should use `Convert.ToDecimal` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`

Comment: A side note: instead of `b = a * (-1)` you can simply use `b = -a`.

Comment: @wohlstad, not just that. They use incorrect types as well.

Comment: @AlexeyZelenin sure. This is why my comment is a side note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to use `decimal` as a variable type if you want to work with decimal numbers
2. If so, use `Convert.ToDecimal` instead of `ToInt32`
3. You don't really need to use multiplication here, it's enough just to use `-a` instead

```cs
string inputData = Console.ReadLine();
decimal a = Convert.ToDecimal (inputData);
decimal b = -a;
Console.WriteLine(b);
Console.ReadLine();
```